# Как пройти по каталогу и подсчитать количество папок и файлов а также сумму размеров всех файлов?

Tags: python

```
def search_and_count_directory_and_file_size(path):
    count_directory = 0
    count_file = 0
    summ_count_size = 0
    for i in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isdir(os.sep.join([path, i])):
            count_directory += 1
        elif os.path.isfile(os.sep.join([path, i])):
            count_file += 1
            summ_count_size += os.path.getsize(os.sep.join([path, i]))
            search_and_count_directory_and_file_size(os.sep.join([path, i]))
            print(os.sep.join([path, i]))

    return count_directory, count_file, summ_count_size

path_in_file = r'C:\Users\Sklad\Python_Basic\Module21'

print(search_and_count_directory_and_file_size(path_in_file))
```

Comment: Да и так и так пробовал Не пойму где засада в таком виде вообще пишет путь неправильный если на папках вызываю  тогда папки считает но внутрь папок не идет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Почему вы вызываете рекурсию, когда вам попадается файл? Вам нужно рекурсивно обходить каталоги, а не файлы, т.е. вызывать рекурсию в той ветке кода, где срабатывает `os.path.isdir`.
2. При рекурсивном вызове функции вы теряете то, что функция возвращает. А нужно это учесть в ваших вычислениях, примерно так:

```py
rec_count_directory, rec_count_file, rec_summ_count_size =\
    search_and_count_directory_and_file_size(os.sep.join([path, i]))
count_directory += rec_count_directory
...
```

Comment: Спс, буду пробовать дальше